# Ошибка в цикле копирования файлов

Tags: c#, ftp

Есть код. На мой взгляд он полностью правилен

```
public static void MyFTP(string localFilePath, string ftpFileName) {

using(FtpConnection ftp = new FtpConnection("87.237.43.11", "123", "123")) {

    ftp.Open(); /* Open the FTP connection */
    ftp.Login(); /* Login using previously provided credentials */

    string yearmonth = localFilePath.Substring(25, 6);
    MessageBox.Show(yearmonth);

    if (ftp.DirectoryExists("/archive/browse/RESURSDK/" + yearmonth)) /* check that a directory exists */ ftp.SetCurrentDirectory("/archive/browse/RESURSDK/" + yearmonth); /* change current directory */

    else ftp.CreateDirectory("/archive/browse/RESURSDK/" + yearmonth);
    //do some processing
    try {
        ftp.SetCurrentDirectory("/archive/browse/RESURSDK/" + yearmonth);
        ftp.PutFile(localFilePath, ftpFileName);

    } catch (FtpException e) {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("FTP Error: {0} {1}", e.ErrorCode, e.Message));
    }

    foreach(var dir in ftp.GetDirectories("/www/")) {
        Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(dir.CreationTime);
        foreach(var file in dir.GetFiles()) {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(file.LastAccessTime);
        }
    }
```

Однако вылетает ошибка

http://postimage.org/image/b6jksqhz9/

Comment: класс FtpConnection из какой библиотеки?

Comment: Код прям так и просит рефакторинга.

Comment: О боже, у вас операции с FTP в UI-потоке. И вы говорите, что ваш код _правилен_?

Comment: А вы бы сами посмотрели, существует такой каталог или нет, а то придётся ждать, пока телепаты подтянутся.

Answer (score 1):

Вам же сообщение чёрным по... гм... бежевому пишет: "directory exists". Вы вызываете метод CreateDirectory, и передаёте ему имя уже существующей директории. Он пытается её создать, а она уже существует. Отсюда ошибка.

Comment: думаю у него вопрос в том почему проверка (создавать, только если не существует) не сработала.

Comment: [Вот][1] исходник библиотеки, которой он пользовался. В методе CreateDirectory всего три строчки, основная задача которых - вызвать функцию из WinAPI. Отсюда вывод: либо косяк в WinAPI (что вряд ли), либо папка действительно есть на сервере (что скорее всего).

  [1]: http://ftplib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/82946#589935

Answer (score 0):

Вот метод CreateDirectory:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a directory on the FTP server.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">A <see cref="String"/> representing the full or relative path of the directory to create.</param>
public void CreateDirectory(string path)
{
    if (WININET.FtpCreateDirectory(_hConnect, path) == 0)
    {
        Error();
    }
}
```

В комменте написано что надо указать или полный путь, или относительный. Вы пользуетесь вторым способом, хотите указать относительный путь. Но подозреваю что путь должен указываться относительно текущей папки, а не рутовой (корневая папка).

**Советы по решению проблемы:** попробуйте указать полный путь папки в параметре функции CreateDirectory.